# htaccess rewrite applying to all, not intended

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my root .htaccess I have

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dashboard/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

In the dashboard folder's .htaccess I have..

```
RewriteRule ^go/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?flag=$1 [L]
```

When I go to dashboard.domain.com/login it throws up an error.
When I go to dashboard.domain.com/go/a it works.

When I # out the dashboard rewrite rule the opposite occurs, /login works, but then /go/$1 doesn't. What am I missing to make the /go rewrite only apply when /go is detected?

EDIT (rest of root htaccess)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rocket/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^launch.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rocket/$1 [NC,L,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dashboard/$1 [NC,L,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /img/$1 [NC,L,NS]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !launch.domain.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://launch.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

Redirect 301 /sneakpeek /

RewriteRule ^error/([^/]+) error/failure.php?code=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|js|json|html|css|php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 400 /error/400
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500
```

Comment: @anubhava "The requested URL /dashboard/login was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
I'll edit the post to include the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules below your dashboard rule might be affecting your rule and changing `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable. You can use `THE_REQUEST` variable and retest it after clearing your browser cache:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(dashboard|error)/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =dashboard.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I change my code to this and clear my cache, it ends up redirecting to a 500 error. This happens with and without the dashboard .htaccess rewrite being commented out. I tried altering the code you provided to be https, since I have a wildcard SSL certificate, but same result.

Comment: Same error. The error logs are showing a bunch of file does not exist for "public_html/dashboard/login" The site is dashboard.rocketlobby.com -- I've reverted back to the original rewrite rules, and don't have the /go rewrite commented out, and it's a 404 error.

Comment: With this rule `https://dashboard.rocketlobby.com/login` will be routed to `https://dashboard.rocketlobby.com/dashboard/login`. Even when I enter `https://dashboard.rocketlobby.com/dashboard/login` directly in my browser it results in 404

Comment: The actual location of the login is rocketlobby.com/dashboard/login.php -- the subdomain dashboard should point to the dashboard folder, so that its location is dashboard.rocketlobby.com/login.php and then i have the remove .php rewrite.

Comment: But then you will need `.php` adding rule in `/dashboard/.htaccess` as well. Having same rule in root .htaccess won't make it work.

Comment: Wow.. -_- That's frustrating. That fixed it all. Thank you!!